# How to relate primary and foreign keys in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, where-clause

I'm trying to solve **Question 5 of the SQL Social-Network Query Exercises (core set)** assignment of **Intro to Databases from Stanford Online Course**.

There are three tables on the **Database**:

```
create table Highschooler(ID int, name text, grade int);
create table Friend(ID1 int, ID2 int);
create table Likes(ID1 int, ID2 int);
```

**Question 5 is**: For every situation where student A likes student B, but we have no information about whom B likes (that is, B does not appear as an ID1 in the Likes table), return A and B's names and grades.

This query is solved with:

```
select distinct H1.name, H1.grade, H2.name, H2.grade
from Highschooler H1, Likes, Highschooler H2
where H1.ID = Likes.ID1 and Likes.ID2 = H2.ID and H2.ID not in (select ID1 from Likes);
```

**My question is:**
In the WHERE clause, is there a difference between putting variables on the left or right side of the equal sign?
For example, is it the same to do **H1.ID = Likes.ID1 and Likes.ID2 = H2.ID** or **Likes.ID1 = H1.ID and H2.ID = Likes.ID2**? Are there any implications?

I'm asking this because I'm new to SQL and I'm used to use the equal sign to assign variables, that I don't know if this is or not the case.

Comment: You shouldn't think of `variables` in the context of sql. Variables belong to the paradigm of imperative programming languages while sql is declarative by nature. The `WHERE` clause in sql represents conditions that matching records  of a resultset must fulfil. So yes, wrt semantics it doesn't matter which way you write the conditions *but* it might make a difference to the query optimizer ( the part of the rdbms code that transforms your query into a sequence of actions in the database ).

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't make any difference. The `WHERE` clause is simply a logical constraint put together from smaller pieces with logical operations.
Logically and mathematically A=B and B=A mean the same thing i.e. they resolve to either `true` or `false` (or `NULL`) depending on the values. The `WHERE` clause itself resolves to `true` or `false` (or `NULL`).

If the query optimizer is from this millenium the order doesn't matter there either.